# MySQL HELP- print the cno, sectno, and the average gpa of the students enrolled in Computer Science

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone guide me on how to figure out the following:

The directions are "too print for each Computer Sciences class, the cno, sectno, and the average gpa of the students enrolled in the class."

I have attached my tables below and my SELECT. Could someone please let me know if my SELECT looks like I am going in the right direction and if so, I am stuck on how to write my ON clause. Do I call the student sid = enroll sid in order to attach these tables; I'm just confused how that would work? Please help guide me, thanks..

```
Student(sid,sname,sex,age,year,qpa)
Dept(dname,numphds)
Prof (pname,dname)
Course (cno,cname,dname)
Major(dname,sid)
Section(dname,cno,sectno,pname)
Enroll(sid,grade,dname,cno,sectno)

SELECT  enroll.dname, enroll.cno, enroll.sectno, student.AVG(gpa)
FROM enroll 
JOIN 'student' on 
WHERE dname = 'Computer Science'
```

Comment: You don't have any criteria for you join clause.  You'll need to connect the two tables:  `from enroll join student on enroll.<somecolumn> = student.<somecolumn>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the join you need to specify on which columns the tables are related, and when using an aggregate function like AVG you need to use the GROUP BY clause.

Something like this:

```
SELECT  enroll.dname, enroll.cno, enroll.sectno, AVG(gpa)
FROM enroll 
JOIN student on student.sid = enroll.sid
WHERE dname = 'Computer Science'
GROUP BY dname, cno, sectno
```

Comment: Ok, I know the enroll.sid is related to student.sid, so I did try connecting those. I wrote the following code 'SELECT  enroll.dname, enroll.cno, enroll.sectno, AVG(gpa) 
FROM enroll 
JOIN 'student' on student.sid = enroll.sid
WHERE dname = 'Computer Science'
GROUP BY dname, cno, sectno;'

Comment: Why wouldn't I use 'student.AVG(gpa)' or does it just work the same? After I made the adjustments you recommended, I still didn't get anything in return.

Comment: @Mel_G using `student.AVG(gpa)` is invalid syntax as it means that AVG is a column in the student table and not a function. `AVG(student.gpa)` would have been correct though.

Comment: Sorry, I keep trying to respond to your questions and hit ENTER too soon. New to this stackoverflow as well.